# Bulk-update a DB table using values from a JSON object

Tags: php, mysql, json, performance

I have a PHP program which gets from an API the weather forecast data for the following 240 hours, for 100 different cities (for a total of 24.000 records; I save them in a single table). The program gets, for every city and for every hour, temperature, humidity, probability of precipitation, sky cover and wind speed. This data is in JSON format, and I have to store all of it into a database, preferably mySQL. It is important that this operation has to be done in a single time for all the cities.

Since I would like to update the values every 10 minutes or so, performance is very important. If someone can tell me which is the most efficient way to update my table with the values from the JSON it would be of great help.

So far I have tried the following strategies:
1) decode the JSON and use a loop with a prepared statement to update each value at a time {too slow};
2) use a stored procedure {I do not know how to pass the procedure a whole JSON object, and I know there is a limited number of individual parameters I can pass};
3) use LOAD DATA INFILE {the generation of the csv file is too slow};
4) use UPDATE with CASE, generating the sql dynamically {the string gets so long that the execution is too slow}.

I will be happy to provide additional information if needed.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that this API will block such traffic.

Comment: Alright, in the introduction I simplified the things a little, but that is not the point of my question. I have a json object and I want to put it into a DB, that is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a single table with about a dozen columns, correct?  And you need to insert 100 rows every 10 minutes, correct?

Inserting 100 rows like that every *second* would be only slightly challenging.  Please show us the SQL code; something must be miserably wrong with it.  I can't imagine how any of your options would take more than a few seconds.  Is "a few seconds" too slow?

Or does the table have only 100 rows?  And you are issuing 100 updates every 10 minutes?  Still, no sweat.

**Rebuild technique:**

If practical, I would build a new table with the new data, then swap tables:

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
Load the data (LOAD DATA INFILE is good if you have a .csv)
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;
DROP TABLE old;
```

There is no downtime -- the `real` is always available, regardless of how long the load takes.

(Doing a massive update is much more "effort" inside the database; reloading should be faster.)

Comment: My mistake, sorry. I meant I have 24.000 rows and I want to update all of them every 10 minutes.
You were right, though, my code was wrong. I have rewritten it and now the query takes ~5 seconds for all the table.
However, since I have to update all the rows in the table, I could be interested in build a new table, what do you think?. In that case, what should I do, Just create a table, insert the data instead of update them, and then rename the tables?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I augmented my answer.